# FATAL EXCEPTION : AsyncTask#5

Tags: android

They have mentionned that the ERROR was occured while excecuting doInBackground()

```
public class NewClientActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText name;
EditText login;
EditText password;
EditText rePassword;
EditText email;
EditText adresse;
EditText tel;

// url to create new product
private static String url_add_client = "http://192.168.1.3/android_connect/add_client.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity1);

    // Edit Text
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewNom);
    login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword);
    rePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewPassword1);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    adresse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewAdresse);
    tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewTel);

    // Create button
    Button btnAddClient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);

    // button click event
    btnAddClient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewClientActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Adding Customer to DataBase..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String Name = name.getText().toString();
        String Login = login.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
    //  String RePassword = rePassword.getText().toString();
        String Email = email.getText().toString();
        String Adresse = adresse.getText().toString();
        String Tel = tel.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", Name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", Login));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", Password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Adresse", Adresse));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Tel", Tel));


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_client,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
            //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
            //  startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
            //  finish();
            } else {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L'inscription n'a pas été éfectuée correctement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Please if you can check it out and tell me where the ERROR is ?? 
thank you in advance !!

Comment: You can not put Toast in AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just override into your `AsyncTask` the method `onProgressUpdate`

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
       ...
       // check for success tag
       try {
           int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

           if (success == 1) {
               // successfully created product
               //  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
               //  startActivity(i);

              // closing this screen
              //  finish();
           } else {
              publishProgress("L'inscription n'a pas été éfectuée correctement");
           }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is because you are trying to update the UI in the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask.

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L'inscription n'a pas été éfectuée correctement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Move the above code to postExecute.

Also the following code in doInBackground wouldn't possibly cause an error to occur

```
    String Name = name.getText().toString();
    String Login = login.getText().toString();
    String Password = password.getText().toString();

    String Email = email.getText().toString();
    String Adresse = adresse.getText().toString();
    String Tel = tel.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L'inscription n'a pas été éfectuée correctement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You are trying to update ui from the background thread ie displaying toast.

Display toast in onPostExecute() or use runonuithread

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
        {
         public void run() 
         { 

         Toast.makeText(NewClientActivity.this,"mymessage", 1000).show();
        }
        });
```

Use a activity context in place of getApplicationContext()

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

For more information check the link below .

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I don't think he will get `NetworkOnUIThreadException` because he is using asyncTask. And also getting view values in `doInBackGround` never cause Exception, it is legal. And the main problem is `Toast`

Comment: @Pragnani i just checked and updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Forget ASyncTask, 
Android Annotations is the better solution!

Look this:
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki